# Why do I get null responses (along with multiple responses) from my JSONAPI query, when I console.log the result? There should only be one return?

Tags: reactjs, axios, drupal-8, json-api

I'm working on a new project, to build a React frontend for a Drupal 8 backend. When I issue a jsonapi query, like:

`http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_descriptor/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91`

I get the following raw result:

```
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "meta": {
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "node--unit_content",
    "id": "a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91",
    "links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
      }
    },
    "attributes": {
      "drupal_internal__nid": 221,
      "drupal_internal__vid": 250,
      "langcode": "en",
      "revision_timestamp": "2020-03-21T18:18:01+00:00",
      "revision_log": null,
      "status": true,
      "title": "Professional Practice",
      "created": "2020-03-21T18:18:01+00:00",
      "changed": "2020-03-26T17:42:21+00:00",
      "promote": false,
      "sticky": false,
      "default_langcode": true,
      "revision_translation_affected": true,
      "path": {
        "alias": null,
        "pid": null,
        "langcode": "en"
      },
      "field_intro": {
        "value": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet tortor varius, luctus urna vel, consequat leo. Cras vulputate neque et sollicitudin rhoncus. Curabitur sed justo eros. Donec id odio blandit, aliquet augue id, porttitor est. Nullam molestie est nec lacus pretium blandit et ut risus. Vivamus suscipit tellus pharetra commodo gravida. Nam nec ex at massa finibus consectetur vehicula id urna. Phasellus nec porta quam, et sodales sapien. Integer id purus luctus, ornare eros a, pellentesque ligula. Donec nisl mi, consequat eget ligula nec, pharetra ultrices tortor. Duis dapibus egestas convallis.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Nunc quam erat, accumsan eu odio iaculis, mollis congue ante. Vivamus auctor, sem ac imperdiet pellentesque, ligula ex fringilla nunc, et posuere massa nisi in arcu. Nam lacinia vel diam ac auctor. Aliquam mollis odio non neque aliquam rhoncus. Aliquam pellentesque dictum tincidunt. Donec interdum purus eu urna venenatis, eu sagittis risus viverra. Nam dictum at enim vitae tincidunt. Morbi pulvinar, risus eget venenatis tincidunt, mi velit molestie ligula, ac cursus enim dui in neque.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Nulla facilisi. Sed malesuada imperdiet feugiat. Sed et tempus justo. In non erat ut enim consectetur porta. Vestibulum erat orci, congue vitae diam at, feugiat volutpat mauris. Phasellus viverra nisl eget nulla laoreet, id efficitur felis rhoncus. Quisque imperdiet, massa a tincidunt egestas, lectus urna auctor mi, quis dapibus risus purus et sem. Donec varius varius justo id luctus. Morbi nibh nibh, suscipit at pharetra non, tristique ac felis. Phasellus eu leo turpis. Suspendisse ac mattis velit. Mauris rhoncus nulla lectus, in sodales nulla congue a. Suspendisse euismod neque diam, vel tincidunt ex rhoncus in. Donec massa orci, tincidunt in malesuada eu, condimentum vel purus. Maecenas dapibus nulla magna, quis facilisis justo varius sit amet.<br />\r\n&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
        "format": "full_html",
        "processed": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet tortor varius, luctus urna vel, consequat leo. Cras vulputate neque et sollicitudin rhoncus. Curabitur sed justo eros. Donec id odio blandit, aliquet augue id, porttitor est. Nullam molestie est nec lacus pretium blandit et ut risus. Vivamus suscipit tellus pharetra commodo gravida. Nam nec ex at massa finibus consectetur vehicula id urna. Phasellus nec porta quam, et sodales sapien. Integer id purus luctus, ornare eros a, pellentesque ligula. Donec nisl mi, consequat eget ligula nec, pharetra ultrices tortor. Duis dapibus egestas convallis.</p>\n\n<p>Nunc quam erat, accumsan eu odio iaculis, mollis congue ante. Vivamus auctor, sem ac imperdiet pellentesque, ligula ex fringilla nunc, et posuere massa nisi in arcu. Nam lacinia vel diam ac auctor. Aliquam mollis odio non neque aliquam rhoncus. Aliquam pellentesque dictum tincidunt. Donec interdum purus eu urna venenatis, eu sagittis risus viverra. Nam dictum at enim vitae tincidunt. Morbi pulvinar, risus eget venenatis tincidunt, mi velit molestie ligula, ac cursus enim dui in neque.</p>\n\n<p>Nulla facilisi. Sed malesuada imperdiet feugiat. Sed et tempus justo. In non erat ut enim consectetur porta. Vestibulum erat orci, congue vitae diam at, feugiat volutpat mauris. Phasellus viverra nisl eget nulla laoreet, id efficitur felis rhoncus. Quisque imperdiet, massa a tincidunt egestas, lectus urna auctor mi, quis dapibus risus purus et sem. Donec varius varius justo id luctus. Morbi nibh nibh, suscipit at pharetra non, tristique ac felis. Phasellus eu leo turpis. Suspendisse ac mattis velit. Mauris rhoncus nulla lectus, in sodales nulla congue a. Suspendisse euismod neque diam, vel tincidunt ex rhoncus in. Donec massa orci, tincidunt in malesuada eu, condimentum vel purus. Maecenas dapibus nulla magna, quis facilisis justo varius sit amet.<br />\n </p>\n"
      },
      "field_unit_code": null
    },
    "relationships": {
      "node_type": {
        "data": {
          "type": "node_type--node_type",
          "id": "ded1db75-f372-47cc-baba-5244e2571aa0"
        },
        "links": {
          "related": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/node_type?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          },
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/relationships/node_type?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          }
        }
      },
      "revision_uid": {
        "data": {
          "type": "user--user",
          "id": "c899de1e-9950-40b4-b879-635b63e14724"
        },
        "links": {
          "related": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/revision_uid?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          },
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/relationships/revision_uid?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          }
        }
      },
      "uid": {
        "data": {
          "type": "user--user",
          "id": "c899de1e-9950-40b4-b879-635b63e14724"
        },
        "links": {
          "related": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/uid?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          },
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/relationships/uid?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          }
        }
      },
      "field_lo_ec_ac": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph--lo_ec_ac",
            "id": "286b325c-7538-4a39-8a94-cfc19faf1b93",
            "meta": {
              "target_revision_id": 3
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "paragraph--lo_ec_ac",
            "id": "d18bdb1d-483d-418c-8bfd-b316afe799ac",
            "meta": {
              "target_revision_id": 5
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "paragraph--lo_ec_ac",
            "id": "5de14184-0933-456a-b69a-6075021182dd",
            "meta": {
              "target_revision_id": 7
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "paragraph--lo_ec_ac",
            "id": "44a82b1f-f79e-44af-9d10-5bda16d5be30",
            "meta": {
              "target_revision_id": 9
            }
          }
        ],
        "links": {
          "related": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/field_lo_ec_ac?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          },
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/relationships/field_lo_ec_ac?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          }
        }
      },
      "field_parent_unit": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "node--unit_descriptor",
            "id": "d79d581b-9b8d-42de-8dbd-82ecbf94287c"
          }
        ],
        "links": {
          "related": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/field_parent_unit?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          },
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91/relationships/field_parent_unit?resourceVersion=id%3A250"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91"
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I run this code in my React:

```
        super()
        this.state={
            loading:false,
            unitContent:{}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){        axios.get(`http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/${this.props.id}`)
        .then(
          response =>{
            const unitContent = response.data;
            this.setState({unitContent})
          }, error => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    }
...
console.log(this.state.UnitContent)
```

And, then run `console.log(this.state.unitContent)` I get four results (two are null, and two are the same)

```
[Log] {} 
[Log] {} 
[Log] {jsonapi: Object, data: Object, links: {self: {href: "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91"}}}
[Log] {jsonapi: Object, data: Object, links: {self: {href: "http://test.site/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91"}}}
```

Why am I getting two empty results, and two duplicates? There is only one record, so shouldn't there only be one return?

Any help, greatly appreciated (as I would then be able to stop including a ton of 'if' to deal with the blanks).

Thanks

Comment: where did you put your console.log()?

Comment: At the start my render method. But I see the same if I put it right after the componentDidMount.

Comment: Put your console log state inside the then call back and remove every other console log you should see two output. let me know so I can explain the reason

Comment: If I put the console.log within the .then of ComponentDidMount, I get a single return.

```{jsonapi: Object, data: Object, links: {self: {href: "http://builder2020.test/jsonapi/node/unit_content/a95f6031-032d-4df0-83d3-42c2b6cc2f91"}}}```

But, the same console.log within the render() method gives two empty and two identical returns.

I cannot see how it is generating additional returns between componentDidMount() and render()